# When I am zooming in or out the page, the layout of my page is getting changed. What should be included in css to prevent this error?

Tags: css

When I am zooming in or out my webpage, the layout is getting totally changed. Whole page is getting messed up. All the div are getting here and there on my page due to zooming. And also bottom scroll bar is also not displayed that's why whole content goes down the page and page looks weird.

In my css coding, somewhere I have used % and somewhere I have used px as parameter units. And also to arrange some contents and div, I have used top and left parameters. Is these are the reasons that my page is behaving like this? Please solve out my problem.

Here's my css code sample:

```
body {
background-color: #AADFF4;
margin: 0 auto;
} 

#header {
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 24%;
background-color: #3180CB;
box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 8px -1px black;
}

#navibar {
margin: auto;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
width: 100%;
height: 5.4%;
position: relative;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px black;
z-index: +100;
}

#logo {
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
left: 8%;
}

#navilinks {
margin: auto;
font-family: "segoe ui light", "sans-serif";
font-size: 170%;
letter-spacing: 2px;
word-spacing: 5px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color: white;
float: left;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bolder;
text-shadow: 0px 7px 10px black;
}

#navilinks:hover {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56 );
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56 );
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56);
color: black;
}

#navilinks2 {
margin: auto;
font-family: "segoe ui light", "sans-serif";
font-size: 25;
letter-spacing: 2px;
word-spacing: 5px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color: white;
float: left;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bolder;
text-shadow: 0px 7px 10px black;
} 


#navilinks2:hover {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56 );
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56 );
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56);
color: black;
}

.drop {
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
visibility: hidden;
background: #2E8D3B;
width: 33.3%;
top: 1%;
-moz-transition: margin 2s ease 0s;
-webkit-transition: margin 2s ease 0s;
-o-transition: margin 2s ease 0s;
-ms-transition: margin 2s ease 0s;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
z-index: +200;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
font-family: "bookman old style", "sans-serif";
}

#navilinks2:hover+.drop, .drop:hover {
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
visibility: visible;
width: 33.33%;
left: 33.33%;
top: 100%;
background: #2E8D3B;
color: white;
font-family: "bookman old style", "sans-serif";
font-size: 20;
-moz-transition: margin 2s ease 0s;
-webkit-transition: margin 2s ease 0s;
-o-transition: margin 2s ease 0s;
-ms-transition: margin 2s ease 0s;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
z-index: +200;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
}

#mainmenu {
margin: auto;
width: 33.333%;
height: 100%;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
float: left;
}

#mainmenu:hover #navilinks2 {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56 );
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56 );
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56);
color: black;
}


#contents {
width: 18%;
height: 150%;
margin: auto;
background-color: transparent;
float: left;
}

#maincontent {
position: relative;
margin: auto;
width: 78%;
min-height: 100px;
float: right;
padding-right: 40px;
padding-left: 10px;
z-index: +50;
}


#footerabc {
position: relative;
margin: auto;
height: 20%;
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
background-color: #3180CB;
top: 150%;
box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 10px 0px black;
z-index: -100;

}


#leftcontent {
margin: auto;
width: 45%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 10px;
}

#subcontent1 {
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 40%;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px black;
}

#rightcontent {
magin: auto;
width: 45%;
height: 100%;
float: right;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}

#gar {
margin: auto;
height: 85%;
width: 38%;
border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
float: left;
}

#gar img {
margin: auto;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
}

#garproduct {
margin: auto;
float: right;
width: 62%;
padding-top: 10px;
text-align: left;
font-family: "verdena", "sans-serif";
font-size: 18;
}

#garproduct2 {
padding-left: 13px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
}

#garproduct2 a {
color: orange;
text-decoration: none;
}

#garproduct2 a:hover {
color: green;
text-decoration: underline;
}


#buttongar {
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
font-size: 25;
height: 12.7%;
padding-top: 10.7px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
float: left;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
color: white;
text-align: left;
}

#buttongar:hover {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56 );
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56 );
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56);
color: black;
}

#products {
margin: auto;
width: 90%;
padding-bottom: 3px;
text-align: center;
color: #AADFF4; 
top: 100;
position: relative;
font-family: "bookman old style", "sans-serif";
font-size: 25;
letter-spacing: 2px;
word-spacing: 5px;
border: solid;
border-color: #AADFF4;
border-width: 1px;
}

#categories {
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
font-family: "bookman old style", "sans-serif";
font-size: 20;
letter-spacing: 2px;
word-spacing: 5px;
top: 120;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 3px; 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
}

#categories:hover {
background: #AADFF4;
color: black;
}


#tagline {
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
right: 8%;
font-size: 40;
font-family: "cooper black", "sans-serif";
text-align: center;
color: #FF6700;
top: 5%;
text-shadow: 0px 5px 10px black;
}

a { 
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}

a:hover { color: black; }

.menu1 {
display: none;
background-color: #AADFF4;
color: black;
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
}


#back {
position: fixed;
height: auto;
width: auto;
margin-top: -2.5%;
margin-left: -5%;
top: 93%;
left: 98%;
border-radius: 10px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-size: large;
z-index: +500;
}

#discloser {
font-size: 25;
text-align: justified;
}

#explore {
position: relative;
top: 40;
padding: 20px;
float: center;
color: black;
font-size: 35;
text-align: center;
font-family: "bookman old style", "sans-serif";
}


#newcategories {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
top: 50;
height: 6.55%;
left: 4%;
margin: auto;
text-shadow: 0px 7px 10px black;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #39B54A, #2E8D3B);
text-align: center;
font-size: 28px;
font-family: "monotype corsiva", sans-serif;
color: white;
-webkit-transition: width, background, color, font-weight, left;
border-top-right-radius: 25px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
z-index: +600;
overflow: visible;
padding-top: 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px black;
}

#newcategories:hover {
width: 110%;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56 );
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56 );
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#FFF200, #F68E56);
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
z-index: +600;
overflow: visible;
}

#sidebar {
position: relative;
top: 47;
width: 100%;
height: 59%;
margin: auto;
background-color: orange;
border-top-right-radius: 55px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 55px;
}

#footercat {
position: absolute;
width: 30%;
top: 20%;
height: 63%;
font-size: 25;
font-family: "monotype corsiva", sans-serif;
text-align: center;
border-right: solid 1px white;
}

#footerright {
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 32%;
height: 45%;
width: 40%;
float: left;
font-size: 25;
font-family: "monotype corsiva", sans-serif;
text-align: left;
}

#social {
position: absolute;
top: 18%;
width: 29%;
font-size: 25;
font-family: "monotype corsiva", sans-serif;
right: 1%;
border-left: solid 1px white;
height: 63%;
}

#social img {
width: 10%;
height: 48%;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px black;
border-radius: 15px;
}

#social img:hover {
box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px white;
}

#topheading {
height: 15%;
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #215688, #3180CB);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #215688, #3180CB);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #215688, #3180CB);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #215688, #3180CB);
z-index: +500;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#heading {
margin: auto;
left: 5%;
padding-top: 8px;
color: white;
font-size: 25;
font-family: "bookman old style", "sans-serif";
padding-left: 10px;
text-align: center; 
}

.fontsize {
font-size: 22;
font-family: "segoe ui light", "sans-serif";
}

#abcd {
font-family: "segoe ui light", "sans-serif";
font-size: 18;
padding-top: 10px;
}
```

This is a part of my full CSS coding.

Comment: Code please? We cant see whats wrong if you dont show us what is wrong

Comment: You can see the css code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to build a responsive design you must avoid some pratics and use some anothers depending on the content. there's not a magic rule you can apply to fix your design. maybe using min-width can help you if you use it on your body tag

```
     body{
          min-width:1000px;
     }
```